# Why does this Wikidata query return no results?

Tags: wikipedia-api, wikidata, wikidata-api

Shouldn't this Wikidata query return something?

```
https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Kevin_Bacon
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not, it shouldn't, [there is no Wikidata page titled "Kevin Bacon"](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon). The Wikidata page containing information about the actor Kevin Bacon is https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q3454165.

This means that the API query https://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Q3454165 will return *something* (specifically, the page id). Without knowing what do you actually want, it's hard to help you further, though it's likely [the Wikidata-specific API methods](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikibase/API) are what you want, instead of `action=query`.